# Convert String to Location in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, serialization, type-conversion

I'm working on an **Android** app in **Kotlin** in which I want to save a 'Location' object to **SQLite** and then recover it later.  I can convert a 'Location' object to a 'String' by simply calling 'toString()' on the 'Location' object like this:

```
var loc:Location
var str:String

... Code to init loc ...

str = loc.toString
```

After which the String has a value such as:

```
str = Location[gps 37.328528,-121.897877 hAcc=8 et=+1d15h4m55s443ms alt=-6.62762451171875 vel=0.36 bear=264.9 vAcc=17 sAcc=3 bAcc=97 {Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=96]}]
```

How do I then convert the resulting String back to a Location object

**Update #1**
This is my attempt to use Gson as per the suggestion by @DivijGupta

```
    constructor(i_productName: String, i_date:String, i_location:Location?)
    {
        var parcel:Parcel?=Parcel.obtain()
        var locStr:String = ""
        
        var longitude:Double
        
        if(i_location!=null) {
            logEntryAction = i_productName
            logEntryDate = i_date
            
            longitude = i_location.longitude
            locStr = Gson().toJson(i_location)   <-----  Gson
        }
        else
        {
            longitude = 0.0
        }
        logEntryLongitude = longitude
```

Comment: Create Json Object from Location object and convert it back to location. You can not change `toString` output to object its exists only for readability purpose

Comment: Do you need a `Location` object? Or the location with maybe altitude and/or accuracy? You could just save the latitude, longitude as `double` in 2 separate columns.

Comment: @JanKubovy as I stated in the question, I am looking to get a 'Location object.'  Preferably an exact copy without having to manually save and reload every field.

Comment: Would someone please let me know why I was downvoted.  I am new to stackoverflow and am trying to use it correctly but I have no idea what I did wrong in this case.

Comment: I know. The `Location` object has tight to the location provider and has some internal (i did not explore) which make it not a good candidate for serialization/deserialization. That's why I suggested to store just the relevant attributes. Depending on what do you want to do with the location you can use some other object to do your operations later (e.g. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates). Could you clarify what do you intend to do with the recovered object later?

Comment: @JanKubovy I was reviewing my questions and see that you are correct.  Could you please put your answer in the Answer section so I can accept it?  A bit of an explanation as to why Location is not a good candidate for serialization/deserialization would be nice too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library for the same.

Add the dependency

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
```

Convert the object to a string

```
val jsonString = Gson().toJson(loc)
```

Now to get the object from string

```
val location = Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Location::class.java)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but Gson().toJson(loc) returned {"mElapsedRealtimeNanos":159085401507914}  I don't understand why since 'loc' is a Location object.  I added the code to my original question under *Update #1*

Comment: I tested it with a Date object and that works fine.  Seems to just have a problem with a Location object???

Comment: Seems like there's a problem with serializing Location objects. Instead, you can create your own class with fields which you want to save from the location object. Then use Gson to serialize the object of your created class.

Comment: My mistake: Neither is Date being serialized by Gson().toJson() properly.  Just getting the toString() output...

Comment: Try the alternative method, that should work.